# dismissViewControllerAnimated Won't stop video play

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewcontroller

Here's the details.

BViewController has a CViewController's instance view as B's subview. CViewController is video controller.

Then I present B's instance in AViewController. But When I call dismissViewcontroller in BViewController, The view did go back to AViewController, but the sound of CViewController's video keeping playing?

In AViewController.m

`[self presentViewController:bViewController animated:YES completion:nil];`

In BViewController.m

```
- (void)clickToDismiss {
    self.cViewController = nil;
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

The results are:

In CViewController, `dealloc` was called.

```
- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"dealloc playview");
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

InAViewController, `clickToDismiss()` was called. but `dealloc()` was not called.

Comment: Are you calling `dismissViewController` to dismiss BViewController? If so you should call it from AViewController, the one that is presenting B. B controller can't dismiss itself.

Comment: Thanks for replying. But how can I call `dismissViewController` from AViewController. Because I've already presented the BViewController, now AViewController is invisible. I only have one exit button on the BViewController.

Comment: UIViewController class has a .presentingViewController property which is populated if controller is presented modally, like in your case. So in your B controller just call `[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];`

Comment: This didn't work. It's like call `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];`, only dismiss the bViewController, but the audio in cViewController is still playing after dismiss and back to AViewController.

Comment: It's hard to understand what's going wrong without all the code for how are you adding controllers and views. Seems like a strong reference somewhere prevents your player from deallocating.